# Storage order for multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, memory-layout

With a C compiler, are array elements are stored in column major order or row major order, or it is compiler dependent?

```
int arr[2][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int array[3][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

on printing arr and array output:
arr:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

array:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

It seems its always prefer row major order?

Comment: You didn't pay much attention to the `-Wmissing-braces` warnings, did you?

Comment: I'm reading a book and it is given------>Like in the case of other variables, declaring a two-dimensional array only reserves space for the
array in the memory. No values are stored in it. A two-dimensional array is initialized in the same
way as a one-dimensional array is initialized. For example,
int marks[2][3]={90, 87, 78, 68, 62, 71};
Note that the initialization of a two-dimensional array is done row by row. The above statement
can also be written as:
int marks[2][3]={{90,87,78},{68, 62, 71}};

Comment: and also this was run without any warning.

Comment: On gcc/clang, you should use at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` (you should use `-pedantic` as well), on VS (`cl.exe`) you should use `/W3`. If you do, you will receive warnings. The declaration for `arr` should have `int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};` Do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Answer (score 4):

Row major order is mandated by the standard.

[6.5.2.1p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p3):

> Successive subscript operators designate an element of a
>   multidimensional array object. If E is an n-dimensional array (n >= 2)
>   with dimensions i x j x . . . x k, then E (used as other than an
>   lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an (n - 1)-dimensional array with
>   dimensions j x . . . x k. If the unary * operator is applied to this
>   pointer explicitly, or implicitly as a result of subscripting, the
>   result is the referenced (n - 1)-dimensional array, which itself is
>   converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. It follows
>   from this that **arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript
>   varies fastest)**.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: I have another problem -why double pointer (**ptr) can not use to access array?

Comment: Because nowhere are pointers stored. Please wipe "double pointer" out of your mind. There are pointers that point to pointers, but that's not a "double pointer".

Comment: I'm seconding gnasher729. Multidimensional arrays ≠ multiply indirect pointers. While you can do `doubly_indirect[1][0]`  (if doubly_indirect is an array of pointers that contains at least 2 pointers) just like `two_dimensional_array[1][0]`, the `[1][0]` mean very different thing in those two contexts,  but that might be a topic for a different question.

Answer (score -1):

You *printed* the array. The output is in whatever order that you printed the array elements. So what you see has nothing to do with the order in which array elements are stored in memory.

int arr[2][3] means that you have three arrays, and the object stored in each array is an int[2]. Objects are always stored consecutively, so the first int[2] is stored in consecutive memory, followed by the second int[2], followed by the third int[2]. And that is the same for *any* C implementation.

Comment: Surely you've got that back to front? Your description would be correct for `int arr[3][2]` but not for `int arr[2][3]`.